# Do I need to release resources of slot parameter in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

As an example, look at this code:

```
QNetworkRequest request(mResultsURL); //our server with php-script

connect(mNetworkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onUploadFinished(QNetworkReply*))); //This slot is used to debug the output of the server script
mNetworkManager->post(request,data);
```

and the corresponding receiving slot:

```
void MyApp::onUploadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){

    QJsonObject root = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();

    // do some work
}
```

so my question is: Do I need to add

```
delete reply;
```

to the end of the function? Or is this handled automatically by Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished), you need to free the resource, but you cannot `delete` the reply inside the slot. You need to call [`deleteLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) instead:

> Note: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the user to delete the QNetworkReply object at an appropriate time. Do not directly delete it inside the slot connected to finished(). You can use the deleteLater() function.
>
> [...]
>
> Note: Do not delete the reply object in the slot connected to this signal. Use deleteLater().

Answer (score 2):

You need to schedule it for deletion like krzaq points:

```
void MyApp::onUploadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    QJsonObject root = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

deleteLater puts your object on a watchlist that Qt runtime checks whenever event loop enters, here are the exceprts from the doc:

> Schedules this object for deletion.
>
> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop. If the event loop is not running when this function is called (e.g.
>   deleteLater() is called on an object before QCoreApplication::exec()),
>   the object will be deleted once the event loop is started. If
>   deleteLater() is called after the main event loop has stopped, the
>   object will not be deleted. Since Qt 4.8, if deleteLater() is called
>   on an object that lives in a thread with no running event loop, the
>   object will be destroyed when the thread finishes.